# Getting too many body parameters error even with single RequestBody for FeignClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I am trying to access one FeignClient method for a remote service.  Even though I have single ResquestBody, I am getting too many parameters error.

My code snippet:

```
/* ValidateServiceProxy */

@FeignClient(name = “validate-service”)
public interface ValidateServiceProxy {

@PostMapping ("api/validate”)
public Response<ValidateResponse> getValidationResponse(
        @RequestBody ValidateRequest validateRequest ,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails userDetails,
        @RequestHeader(name = “unique-Key") String uniqueKey) throws
        ConnectTimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException;
```

}

Error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [ValidateService]: Factory method 
'ValidateServiceProxy' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters:
```

I have gone through similar questions but did not find solution to my problem.

Let me know what went wrong.

EDIT:

After removing  `@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails userDetails` in API, it worked. Looks like `AuthenticationPrincipal` is treated as body.

Even though the problem is solved temporarily, need to know how to pass `AuthenticationPrincipal`  with out getting the error.

Comment: Please add the full error/stacktrace the current one has far too little information in it.

Comment: I have renamed the class and method to hide important business logic.  Updated some more info on Exception. Error (Method has too many Body parameters) simply shows method signature and return type

Comment: I doubt that that is still the whole message, as stated please include the whole error and if you have a stacktrace. We need more information as there is far too little information currently to help you.

Comment: after removing  @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails userDetails in API, it worked. Looks like AuthenticationPrincipal is treated as body.

Comment: That would have been my guess as well, but some information would have been in the stacktrace (at least I assume). The `@AuthenticationPrincipal` isn't supported by feign, what you should do is send the proper headers (token, basic auth) to your client.

Comment: Yaa. I have resolved it as per your suggestion. Sending with a different RequestHeader Token